# Hardware: is stacking multiple heatsinks useful?

Tags: raspberry-pi, cooling, heatsink

I'm ordering a Raspberry Pi 4B with 8GB of RAM. Along with that I ordered the SD card, some kind of case, etc. (I will be running a Minecraft server on it, very CPU heavy stuff.) [The case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09QG349ZL) leaves plenty of free (physical) space above my Pi board when it's installed. To my surprise, the case came with a heatsink!

But I had already ordered [heatsinks separately](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZLZRDXZ), and therefore I had 3 heatsinks sitting in front of me. Without gluing them, I did test and confirm that all heatsinks can be stacked on top of each other and fit inside the case.

With the heatsink pile so high, the cooling fan was blowing right through them (that shouldn't be a problem once they are properly glued in with thermal glue). When on top of each other, of course the heatsinks do touch at their smallest points (the little spikes on top). But some kind of heat must be able to flow through those little spikes to the top of the pile, right?? Plus, this would effectively form "holes" (where the "spikes" and the flat surface of the next heatsink touch) which the fan can blow air through, making cooling a lot more efficient. *Probably.*

So, **is stacking multiple heatsinks on top of each other safe? And would it negatively affect my Pi's thermal performance?** (I'm not going to buy another Pi anytime soon so a second heatsink would just lie around unused if the answer is no.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a thermal engineer nor do I play one on TV, but its worth thinking about  the actual physics of heatsinks. You have a chip and a heatsink - ideally with as much surface area between them as possible in contact to transfer heat effectively by conduction. The bases of heatsinks are smooth or even polished with the heat sink compound or thermal pads acting to fill those gaps. The heatsink both holds thermal energy (hence sink) it absorbs and gives it up to air, which carries away heat via conduction and (more efficient) convection.

'Stacking' heatsinks means the first heatsink can't convect heat away as effectively, since there's another heatsink or two in the way, you have interfaces between heatsinks that are terrible, and the only advantage *if* all other things were optimal is more thermal mass.

A single heatsink and fan, and a well ventilated case is probably all you need.

Answer (score 1):

I have this and other electronic gear with heatsinks attached to chips. These are engineered to dissipate heat properly. Adding a heat sink on top would require thermal heat transfer.

The top of a heat sink as we are discussing has a non flat top surface to enhance heat dissipation.

Since the bottom of your heat sink is flat, I do not see how proper thermal heat transfer could take place.

I suggest not adding a heat sink as you suggest. It won't work and will not properly dissipate heat.

If you see excessive heat, you might then try a larger (thicker) heat sink (but not two)

My own RP 4 has a small fan in the case. My RP 3 does not.

From [Rapsberry PI Heat Sink](https://linuxhint.com/does-raspberry-pi-4-need-cooling-fan/#:%7E:text=Passive%20cooling%2C%20like%20adding%20a,it%27s%20enclosed%20in%20a%20casing.)

> Like its predecessors, Raspberry Pi 4 B does not contain a built-in
> ventilation system. It wasn’t really a problem with the previous
> generations considering that their specs are lower. Passive cooling,
> like adding a heatsink, would usually keep the components cool. In
> most cases, it’s not even necessary. However, with Raspberry Pi 4’s
> specs, even a heatsink may not be enough if the Pi is used extensively
> and even more so if it’s enclosed in a casing.